# Insert a plain text list to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a very long list in plain text which I need to insert into a table my database. Do I have to manually input each line of my plain text document or is there a way to insert long lists into independent rows in a table using a query?

I have a table with 2 columns, id and club_name, club_name is the list which is plain text in a notepad document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/loading-tables.html), e.g.:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet
-> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

You can also use the [multi-row insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) syntax (if you are using InnoDB tables), like this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable VALUES (1,2), (5,5), ...
```

Comment: I should have mentioned it's around 2000 lines I need to insert, which method would you recommend for that number of text lines?

Comment: @huddds for that low a number of lines, I don't really think that it matters. Go with whatever method you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data into mysql using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command.

Here is the documentation...
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    $file = file("content.txt"); //read file line by line
    foreach ($file as $val) {
        if (trim($val) != '') { //ignore empty lines
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO xxx SET club='" . $val . "'");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) based example, but MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command may be a much better option if you don't need to manipulate the source data (trim, normalise etc).

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL, ?)');
foreach(file('list.txt') as $club) {
    $stmt->execute(array($club));
}
```

Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with php, mysqli and a text file that has each entry on a single line:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$file = file("list.txt"); //read file line by line
    foreach ($file as $val) {
        if (trim($val) != '') { //ignore empty lines
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`column`) VALUES ('$val');";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This is based off of DanFromGermany's answer but updated to use mysqli.

Answer (score -1):

Insert the whole notepad content to a column of type "text"